# Remove content when CMS page is viewed?

Tags: magento2, cms

**Magento 2.4**

Is it somehow possible to remove parts of the content of a CMS page before it is shown to the user? Is there a renderer I could overwrite?

**Example:** The content of my CMS page is this: `hello world, what a nice day today!`

Before it is shown to the user, I want to remove the "today", but not from the page itself, just when the page is being viewed.

Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be several ways to do this, I am sharing here 2 methods which I am aware of

- Replace the content in the server itself
- Replace the content in the client

**Method 1:**

You can do this either by after plugin or by using observer here I am proving an ex using observer

Create a events.xml file to subscribe cms_page_render event. This event will be triggered after the cms content is generated.

```
<event name="cms_page_render">
    <observer name="your_module_cms" instance="Your\Module\Observer\AffectCmsPageRender" />
</event>
```

Create the Observer Model where you can modify the content as per your need

```
class AffectCmsPageRender implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $page = $observer->getPage();
        $content = $page->getContent();
        /**
         * Modify Content as per your need
         */
        $page->setContent($content);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Method 2:**

Use JavaScript to modify the content before its visible to the user using require js 'domReady!'

Comment: I went with the observer method, works like a charm, BIG THANKS!